# insert on duplicate update with select

Tags: mysql

I have `tableA` that stores information about users, lets assume there is one user (`UserA`) saved in the table already, and I want to create a second one (`UserB`) copying the data that `UserA` has.

I will do something like this:

```
Insert into tableA (userID, switch, plateType, groupVal, brokeage)
  Select 'UserB', switch, plateType, groupVal, brokeage
  from tableA 
  where userID = 'UserA';
```

and that is ok.

Now sometimes I have to read the data `UserA` has, and update `UserB` with it, but need to do it in the same query above, so I need to use on duplicate key.

I have written this but it is not working, I've been researching but can't find the answer I need:

```
Insert into tableA (userID, switch, plateType, groupVal, brokeage)
  Select 'UserB', switch, plateType, groupVal, brokeage
  from tableA
  where userID = 'UserA'
on duplicate key
  Update tableA brokeage = (Select brokeage
                            from tableA
                            where userID = 'UserA')
  where userID = 'UserB';
```

If anyone can see what is wrong with this, I will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
Insert into tableA (userID, switch, plateType, groupVal, brokeage) 
Select 'UserB', switch, plateType, groupVal, brokeage 
from tableA 
where userID = 'UserA' 
on duplicate key Update brokeage = (
  Select brokeage 
  from tableA 
  where userID = 'UserA');
```

See the update structure, it will update the duplicate line, no need to precise the where of the tablename.

Comment: thank you very much Rob, it did work, but not the way i expected, because on duplicate did not work...my mistake, i forgot to write, that the primary key uses an auto increment value, i don't know if this affects, if it does please let me know